# Hide .jsp extension or change display name on URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to hide .jsp extension or change display name on URL?

I'm using servlet-jsp communication. my web.xml code is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pub</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/publications.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pub</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/publications</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SciArchive</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.SciArchiveController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SciArchive</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.sci</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I want to hide .jsp extenstion in URL `..../SciArchive/publications.jsp`
to `..../SciArchive/publications`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You already have `publications.jsp` mapped to a URL-pattern. Why are you not using this URL pattern to access the jsp. ?

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>pub</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/publications.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>pub</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/publications</url-pattern> <!-- Use this URL -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you hit the URL `http://somehost/SciArchive/publications` , it will automatically call your jsp in the back-ground and the URL will remain the same (without the page name i.e without .jsp).

Comment: @DownVoter I don't mind criticism but can you comment and explain what is wrong ?

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was useful and solved your problem

Comment: Is there any short way of writing this if you have too many jsp files ?

Comment: @byksl Depends on your situation. Can you post a new question and explain a bit more.