# URL rewrite in jsp remove the extn java

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting

When I run my program link which is generated.

**http://localhost:8084/urlrewrite_program/newjsp.jsp**

I want to remove the .jsp in this link like

**http://localhost:8084/urlrewrite_program/newjsp**

I Have create WEB-INF/web.xml, using the code which is here below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" 
"http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
<rule>
<from>/urlrewrite_program/newjsp.jsp(.*)</from>
<to type="forward">/newjsp</to>
</rule>

<outbound-rule>
<from>^/?([a-z]+)(.(jsp|jspx))$</from>
<to>$1</to>
</outbound-rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326451/hide-jsp-extension-or-change-display-name-on-url

Comment: please explain bro this code is not working ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<from>/(.*).jsp$</from>
<to type="forward">$1</to>
```