# How to remove or hide .jsp extension in url

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

can anyone pls let me know how can mask ur or hide/remove .jsp extension in url
existing url -->  http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp.it needs to change like this http://localhost:8080/test/index    without affect functionality.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326451/hide-jsp-extension-or-change-display-name-on-url

Answer (score 1):

It is a tweek but you can handle it also....Below is my code :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: thank you abhishek for your reply. I need to do it in existing project which has many jsp's, it is difficult to map eveything in web.xml. Is there any way to achieve this using javascript?

Comment: No. Browsers does not allow it.